# ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames even with if statement

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I'm trying to pull all of the 2016 NY Times articles that have the word "economy" in them using the Times' API. I get the following error message at the end of my code:

ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'abstract'

And here is my code:

```
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI
api = articleAPI('0282db2f333f4f4095edd19f0660c978')

articles = api.search( q = 'economy', 
 fq = {'headline':'economy', 'source':['Reuters','AP', 'The New  
 YorkTimes']}, 
 begin_date = 20151231)

def parse_articles(articles):

news = []
for i in articles['response']['docs']:
    dic = {}
    dic['id'] = i['_id']
if i['abstract'] is not None:
        dic['abstract'] = i['abstract'].encode("utf8")
    dic['headline'] = i['headline']['main'].encode("utf8")
    dic['desk'] = i['news_desk']
    dic['date'] = i['pub_date'][0:10] # cutting time of day.
    dic['section'] = i['section_name']
    if i['snippet'] is not None:
        dic['snippet'] = i['snippet'].encode("utf8")
    dic['source'] = i['source']
    dic['type'] = i['type_of_material']
    dic['url'] = i['web_url']
    dic['word_count'] = i['word_count']

    locations = []
    for x in range(0,len(i['keywords'])):
        if 'glocations' in i['keywords'][x]['name']:
            locations.append(i['keywords'][x]['value'])
    dic['locations'] = locations

    subjects = []
    for x in range(0,len(i['keywords'])):
        if 'subject' in i['keywords'][x]['name']:
            subjects.append(i['keywords'][x]['value'])
    dic['subjects'] = subjects   
    news.append(dic)
return(news) 

def get_articles(date,query):

all_articles = []
for i in range(0,100): 
    articles = api.search(q = query,
           fq = {'source':['Reuters','AP', 'The New York Times']},
           begin_date = 20151231,
           end_date = 20160715,
           sort='oldest',
           page = str(i))
    articles = parse_articles(articles)
    all_articles = all_articles + articles
return(all_articles)

econ_all = []
for i in range(2015,2016):
print 'Processing' + str(i) + '...'
econ_year =  get_articles(str(i),'economy')
econ_all = econ_all + econ_year


import csv
keys = econ_all[0].keys()
with open('econ-mentions.csv', 'wb') as output_file:

dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
dict_writer.writeheader()
dict_writer.writerows(econ_all)
```

It seems my if statement should prevent the error. Also, if I use "writerow" as I've seen sometimes mentioned on here I get the entire list of details without creating the csv. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was your problem, but this code creates a file econ-mentions.csv with content.

```
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI


def parse_articles(articles):
    news = []
    for i in articles['response']['docs']:
        dic = {}
        dic['id'] = i['_id']
    if i['abstract'] is not None:
        dic['abstract'] = i['abstract'].encode("utf8")
        dic['headline'] = i['headline']['main'].encode("utf8")
        dic['desk'] = i['news_desk']
        dic['date'] = i['pub_date'][0:10] # cutting time of day.
        dic['section'] = i['section_name']
        if i['snippet'] is not None:
            dic['snippet'] = i['snippet'].encode("utf8")
        dic['source'] = i['source']
        dic['type'] = i['type_of_material']
        dic['url'] = i['web_url']
        dic['word_count'] = i['word_count']

        locations = []
        for x in range(0,len(i['keywords'])):
            if 'glocations' in i['keywords'][x]['name']:
                locations.append(i['keywords'][x]['value'])
        dic['locations'] = locations

        subjects = []
        for x in range(0,len(i['keywords'])):
            if 'subject' in i['keywords'][x]['name']:
                subjects.append(i['keywords'][x]['value'])
        dic['subjects'] = subjects   
        news.append(dic)
    return(news) 

def get_articles(date,query):
    all_articles = []
    for i in range(0,100): 
        articles = api.search(q = query,
               fq = {'source':['Reuters','AP', 'The New York Times']},
               begin_date = 20151231,
               end_date = 20160715,
               sort='oldest',
               page = str(i))
        articles = parse_articles(articles)
        all_articles = all_articles + articles
    return(all_articles)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = articleAPI('0282db2f333f4f4095edd19f0660c978')

    articles = api.search( q = 'economy', 
     fq = {'headline':'economy', 'source':['Reuters','AP', 'The New YorkTimes']}, 
     begin_date = 20151231)

    econ_all = []
    for i in range(2015,2016):
        print 'Processing' + str(i) + '...'
        econ_year =  get_articles(str(i),'economy')
        econ_all = econ_all + econ_year

    import csv
    keys = econ_all[0].keys()
    with open('econ-mentions.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(econ_all)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Interestingly, it does create content but I'm not sure if it captured all articles with the word economy in it. But this helps...I will keep working.